# I can't add service at VS2008 to Sharepoint services

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, service

I can't add service at VS2008 to Sharepoint services
when i tried to

http://tomasekweb.com/Test1/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx
and click on GO

The user and password was needed,I typed it but, it's still needed. 
I don't know, what i have to set on sharepoint site.
I have only one user on Sharepoint server.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've put the server name in that URL?

You should put the full path to the web service including server name, and after that convert it to a dynamic web service so that you can adjust the URL appropriately at runtime (through configuration or within the code).

If the path is correct (and full) then the connection should work fine.

If it still isn't working, consider whether you are connecting to the sharepoint instance via a proxy. Windows Authentication does not work over proxies due to the authentication token only being able to make one network hop... this is known as the double-hop bug. It's not really a bug, it's by design and is designed to prevent man in the middle attacks... so don't use a proxy.

Comment: It still doesn't work.
I don't use proxy. 
I see the list of Web Method, when i use the advanced and Add Web Reference but i has to cancel autentication.
It's a Discovery Credential window for autentication.